# Androidstudio - gradle - cordova: import.org.apache.cordova.* fails

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-studio

because of a high priority security fix in cordova for android we need to update our cordova version (from 2.7.0 to 3.6.3) in our app. So we thought it would be better to create a new project.

I installed cordova and create a project with cordova cli api. Also I added the android platform added many cordova plugins. Then I copied our sencha touch stuff into the www folder.

Then I called "cordova build android" (before I also called "cordova prepare android").

After that I imported this android project in Android Studio (0.8.11).

I needed to configure the gradle files a bit (buildToolsVersion, etc.)

For our app I needed to copy the following things from our old project

- AndroidManifest.xml
- All the stuff out of the res/ directory
- in the src/ directory I added some stuff we need in our app

Then I recognized that the android-support android-support-v13.jar library was missing in the lib/ folder. So I copied it out of the sdk\extras\android\support\v13 directory. After that nearly all red stuff in the code disappeared, so I tried to run it.

The app starts but I'm getting many errors like: "Cordova exec fail: Class not found".

So I looked into our src/ directory and there in our java files. There is everything red because the impor of

`import org.apache.cordova.*;` or

`import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;`

fails.

The needed java files I found in `/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes/com/org/apacke/cordova/`

Is there anything which I still need to configure?

My gradle file dependencies:

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
        compile project(subproject)
    }
}`

Please help me/ Thanks ahead!! :-)